# Django custom login form will not validate against is_valid()

Tags: django, forms, validation, authentication

**Summary:**
My custom login form is failing to validate against .is_valid().  I have been able to confirm the email & password values are being passed through to views.py as *print(request.POST.get('')* returns both the email (required for login) and the password.

I think my issue is different from other similar questions because they all seem to address missing required fields.  I tried excluding every field I could think of from .is_valid but the form won't validate.

I click the button and nothing happens (data moves which is strange because the form still doesn't validate validate and my login doesn't work -  see my logs at the bottom) .  I am using Django 3.7.

**accounts/forms.py**

```
    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='email', max_length='255')
        password = forms.CharField(label='password')
        
        def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = request
            super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.save()
            return super(LoginForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

**accounts/views.py**
I can't access anything inside the "form.is_valid" if statement.  I exit at the corresponding else statement (noted below).

```
    def login_page(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':  #create form instance / populate
             form = LoginForm(request.POST)
             context = {
            "email": "email",
            "password": "password",
            "first_name": "first_name",
            "last_name": "last_name",
            "is_active": "is_active",
            "form": form
            } 
            if form.is_valid():  
                username = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                form.save()
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        print(request.is_authenticated())
                        context['form'] = LoginForm()
                        return redirect('/')
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
            else: 
                '''This is where I always end up in the code'''                                      
                print("Error with if form.is_valid():")
                return render(request, "account/login.html", context)
        else:
            return render(request, "account/login.html")
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```
    app_name = 'accounts'

    from .views import login_page

    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', login_page, name="login")
        ]
```

**login.html**

```
    {% extends '_base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

    {% block title %}Login{% endblock title %}

    {% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>

    {% endblock content %}
```

**settings.py**
I have all the required apps that django recommends for authentication as well as backends.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.sites',

        # Third-party
        'crispy_forms',

        # Local
        'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig'
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]


    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'carts:cart_update'
    ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'accounts.forms.LoginForm'}
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
        'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
    ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
    ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
    ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
    ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
    ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 4
    ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 300
```

**accounts/model.py - Custom User Model**
The tutorial I was working off of used a custom user file but I am not sure if this is part of the problem or not.  I suspect it is not related but I'm including it just in case.

```
    DEFAULT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_ACTIVATION_DAYS', 7)

    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, email, first_name=None, last_name=None,                 
        password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
                raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
               raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        user_obj = self.model(
               email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) # change user password
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.is_active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

        def create_staffuser(self, email,first_name=None, last_name=None,         
             password=None):
             user = self.create_user(
                    email,
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                    password=password,
                    is_staff=True
            )
            return user

        def create_superuser(self, email, first_name=None,last_name=None, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
    )
    return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True, null=True) # can login
        staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True) # staff user non superuser
        admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True) # superuser
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #username
        # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #['full_name'] #python manage.py createsuperuser

        objects = UserManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email

        def get_first_name(self):
            if self.first_name:
                return self.first_name
            return self.first_name

        def get_email(self):
           return self.email

        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return True

        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return True

        @property
        def is_staff(self):
            if self.is_admin:
                return True
            return self.staff

        @property
        def is_admin(self):
            return self.admin
```

**Here are my logs:**
I have confirmed print(request.POST.get('') returns both the email and password so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
    web_1  | <tr><th><label for="id_email">email:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" maxlength="255" required id="id_email"></td></tr>
    web_1  | <tr><th><label for="id_password">password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required id="id_password"></td></tr>
    web_1  | Error with if form.is_valid():
    web_1  | [20/Mar/2021 10:16:21] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3192
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting 1 `form.errors` after `is_valid`?

Comment: Yes, I only appear to be getting a blank dictionary {}.  Which means it's unbound for some reason?  I don't understand because I can call the fields (print(request.POST.get('email')) and print(request.POST.get('password')))  and it shows the input data.  So it has access to the data.  I don't understand why the two fields won't validate.

Comment: Doesn't look like you instantiate the form in your view.

Comment: is your indentation as shown in the question? if so, the form.isvalid and below needs to be indented to be part of the if requests is POST block.

Comment: Yes, my indentation was messed up.  I've corrected it.  I thought the problem might be my backend since i'm using email as a login.   But I think my problem happens earlier than that.  is_valid only returns True when return self.is_bound and not self.errors.  I don't think the fields in my form are empty (I can pull data with request.POST.get()).  So that must mean I have an error in the form, or maybe I'm missing fields. But what fields other than email & password?  The fields in my User model?  Going to keep researching but I'm having trouble pulling error messages for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.  It turned out the form was not bound even though all the required fields were present.  I tried loads of different suggestions but ultimately it came down to modifying form = LoginForm(request.POST) to form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST).  For some reason having two request.POST allowed the form to pass the is_valid test.  I don't understand why as I never see this option in any of the tutorials, etc.

Comment: LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST) or you can do LoginForm(data=request.POST) second one seems much more logical.